# Convert python to exe using py2exe

Tags: python, matplotlib, py2exe

My goal is to convert a py file to an exe file.

I have a python file that uses the following libraries:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import numpy as np 
import scipy import signal
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import Tkinter as Tk 
import tkFileDialog
```

the setup file I used:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(
      console =['name of my python file'],
)
```

I had followed the tutorials on youtube and had successfully created an exe file.
but when I ran it, I obtained the following feedback.

```
Could not find the matplotlib data files.
```

Would you tell me what happens and provide me with a solution? 
thank you very much.

Comment: Did you check if `matplotlib` can be packaged into an exe file? There are some modules that cannot be put into an exe file by p2exe.

Comment: I don't remember the exact location of the other question, but i'm pretty sure this is a duplicate. You might want to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

There is tutorial on py2exe website on how to use matplotlib.
http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/MatPlotLib